# Nginx - Block country from accessing website

Tags: nginx, geoip

I have an nginx server and get a lot of junk traffic from CN/JP and some UK.

how can i block access to these countries?
i have tried GeoIP and cant get it to work...

Part of file: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
http {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    geoip_country /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;
    map $geoip_country_code $allowed_country {
        default yes;
        CN no;
        JP no;
    }

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
```

Part of file: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
(a location block inside my HTTPS section for testing)

```
    location /geo {
    if ($allowed_country = no) {
            return 444;
    }
    }
```

`nginx -t`
comes back clean with success

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

`/etc/init.d/nginx restart`
comes back clean with [OK]

```
Restarting nginx nginx          [OK]
```

I want CN/JP to get either a 444 no header sent or 403 denied. Something so they get no content access on the site. but other countries get to access.

My logs are just full of access after access from these two countries.

Comment: Does `nginx -t` come back clean? Because I'm pretty sure you have to quote those `"yes"` and `"no"`s.

Comment: @Sammitch i just tried wrapping the yes & no in "yes" "no"... and it didnt help still same result not blocking cCN/JP connections (tested with a VPN in JP)

Comment: @Twml are you able to find any solution ?